# Residuals in Univariate interpolation in python

Tags: python, interpolation, resampling

I am trying to resample some data (well log data, in my case resistivity vs depth) and I need to associate errors to my resampled data.
I chose to do it through an Univariate spline function, how can I calculate
residuals for every point (error bars)?
My original data are considered errorless.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import seaborn as sns


depth, resistivity = np.loadtxt('resistivity.txt', unpack=True)

#resampling (every 10 m depth)
depth_coarse = depth[::20] 

resistivity_spline = UnivariateSpline(depth, resistivity, k=1, s=1)

#plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.5,10))
figure_title = 'Resistivity Log resampled'

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

plt.text(0.5, 1.08, figure_title,
     horizontalalignment='center',
     fontsize=20,
     transform = ax.transAxes)


ax.plot(resistivity, depth, c='grey', label='data', alpha=0.6)
ax.plot(resistivity_spline(depth_coarse), depth_coarse, '-x',     label=r'data resampled $\Delta z = 10$ m')


ax.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)
ax.set_xlabel('Resistivity (ohm m)')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.set_ylabel('Depth (m)')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.invert_yaxis()


plt.show()
```

[image: my plot]

Sorry for being naive, I'm really new in programming:/

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "calculate residuals for every point". What exactly do you want the measure of error to be?

Comment: I want to do a cross-correlation between those resistivity data and some velocity data of the same borehole. Basically I have to do a cross plot resistivity-velocity and then fit it. I want to do the chi-square of the fit, so I must have errors associate to my data..and I guess the resampling error could be an appropriate one..

Comment: So you want one error for each data point or one error for the whole fit? In the former case, one could calculate the distance between the spline and the original data `resistivity_spline(depth_coarse) -  resistivity[::20]`. In the latter case [`UnivariateSpline.get_residual()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.get_residual.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.get_residual) might be an option to look at.

Comment: Thank you very much in the end it was simple, I got just to calculate the distance between the spline and the original signal!